# What mobile wallets support EIP67

Tags: wallets, mobile-wallet

What mobile wallets support scanning qr codes that are created using the EIP67 standard? [Link to EIP67](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67)

Answer (score 3):

WALLETH (http://walleth.org) supports ERC-67 and soon ERC-681 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/681)

Comment: Thank you, this is a neat project. I just sent you and email with some feedback and an idea about ENS+ERC67.

Comment: Received and answered.

Comment: Sadly those pub keys are well dead.

Comment: kk - just send unencrypted again